# Qml: use Text's elide property with textFormat: RichText

Tags: qt, qml

I have an RSS feed with escaped HTML characters that I want to display in a Text component where I trim the excess content with `elide: Text.ElideRight` and `wrapMode: text.WordWrap`.

While this works very well for plain text, when I use `textFormat: Text.RichText` the trimming does not work.

How can I make the trimming to work or, if this is impossible, encode the HTML easily prior to binding it to the text component?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed `Text` doesn't support `elide` for `Text.RichText`.

There is a [bug open](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16567) on the Qt bug tracker, and after the first reply there is a possible solution, that I copy and paste here for an easy read:

```
TextEdit {
    property string htmlText: "<b>"+workingText.text+"</b>"
    text: htmlText
    width: parent.width
    onHtmlTextChanged: {elide();}
    onWidthChanged: elide();//Yes, this will be slow for dynamic resizing and should probably be turned off during animations
    function elide(){//Also, width has to be set, just like elide, or it screws up
        text = realText;
        var end = richText.positionAt(width - 28,0);//28 is width of ellipsis
        if(end != realText.length - 7)//Note that the tags need to be taken care of specially.
        text = realText.substr(0,end + 3) + '…' + '</b>';//3 is + <b>
    }
    font.pixelSize: 22
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a simple workaround which works quite well in my case, where the width and height of the Text component are fixed, i.e. trimming the string manually. The end result depends a bit on how monospace your font is.

```
text:  {
    var name = "my very very long text string with HTML markup&nbsp;that goes on forever and ever and ever"
    var text = name.substring(0,45)
    if (name.length > 45) text += "..."
        return text
}
```

Comment: Actually, this approach has a problem: HTML entities count for their width. &copy; is 6 characthers long, but it occupies only 1 char in your text.

If there are three entities in one string, you lose 18-20 chars just to display 3 chars