# QML: Wrap Text to height when using RichText

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to display a long(ish) HTML file in a QML `Text` object.

When the text is longer than can be displayed in the current viewport, it gets chopped off
(i.e. only half of the last line of text is shown and the bottom half is hidden).

Ordinarily, I'd use elide or maximumLineCount, but none of those properties work when using Rich Text.
Since this is a full HTML document it has to be RichText not StyledText.

Example:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 300;
    height: 400;
    Text {
        id: text
        anchors.fill: parent
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        text: "..."
    }
}
```

What kind of properties/changes could I add to either the Text or the Rectangle to make it only show the text that can be shown in the given width and height?

The only other question related to this one that I could find was [Qml: use Text's elide property with textFormat: RichText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921385/qml-use-texts-elide-property-with-textformat-richtext), but that wasn't practical in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better wrapping your `Text` component inside a container like [ScrollView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html). [Flickable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) is another alternative.

```
ScrollView {
  width: 300
  height: 400
  clip: true

  Text {
    id: text
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: "..."
  } 
}
```

Or... if you really want to put the text inside a `Rectagle` and clip its content, then simply set `clip` property of your `Rectangle` to `true`.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 400
    clip: true

    Text {
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually was already using Flickable, I just used Rectangle for this example.
I've tried ScrollView, Flickable, etc. I've tried setting clip in the ScrollView and in the Text. Nothinging works. The bottom half of the text still gets chopped off.

Answer (score 0):

I am still looking for a better solution than below. With *better* I don't mean something that would do a binary search, instead of shrinking from the end.

```js
var paras = content.text.match(/<p(.*?)>.*?<\/p>/g);

if (content.contentHeight > content.height) {
    for (let i = paras.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       let para = paras[i];
       let words = para.replace('</p>','').split(' ');
       for (let j = words.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
           paras[i] = words.slice(0, j).join(' ') + '</p>';
           content.text = paras.join('');
           if (content.contentHeight <= content.height) break;
       }
       if (content.contentHeight <= content.height) break;
    }
}
```

From [CSS: Can you prevent overflow: hidden from cutting-off the last line of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220812/css-can-you-prevent-overflow-hidden-from-cutting-off-the-last-line-of-text) and [QML Text: how to use CSS properties, e.g. text-decoration: overline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141592/qml-text-how-to-use-css-properties-e-g-text-decoration-overline) I tried if the solution below could work as text property. Only later to find out [column-width](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#block-attributes) not being supported (yet) in QT.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style=\"width: 1168px; height: 576px; overflow: hidden;\">
            <div style=\"column-width: 1168px; -webkit-column-width:1168px; height: 576px;\">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```